# How to connect Wi-Fi programmatically in Android 10

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, android-10.0, networkspecifier

I have written Wi-Fi connection function for Android 10. It works on Android 10 version mobile phones. It connects the respective Wi-Fi, but after the successful connection of Wi-Fi. It lost the access of internet.

My app requirement is connect Wi-Fi programmatically with internet access. So, please help me finding the solution for that.

My function is given below,

```
public static void connectToWiFi(final Context cntx, String ssid, String key) {
    int securityType = 1;
    int highestPriorityNumber = 0;
    WifiConfiguration selectedConfig = null;

    mainWifiObj = (WifiManager)  cntx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        System.out.println("Wi-Fi Status: "+ mainWifiObj.isWifiEnabled());
        if (!mainWifiObj.isWifiEnabled()) {
            returnWifConnection("1234", "enableWifi");
        }
    }else{
        if (!mainWifiObj.isWifiEnabled()) {
            mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("Wifi is enabled");
        }
    }
    /* Check if not connected but has connected to that wifi in the past */
    for (WifiConfiguration config : mainWifiObj.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
        if (config.priority > highestPriorityNumber) highestPriorityNumber = config.priority;
        if (config.SSID.equals(quoted(ssid)) && config.allowedKeyManagement.get(securityType)) {
            System.out.println("Saved preshared key is " + config.preSharedKey);

            if (securityType == WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK
                    && config.preSharedKey != null && config.preSharedKey.equals(key))
                selectedConfig = config;

            else if (securityType == WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE)
                selectedConfig = config;
        }
    }

    if (selectedConfig != null) {
        selectedConfig.priority = highestPriorityNumber + 1;
        mainWifiObj.updateNetwork(selectedConfig);
        // mainWifiObj.disconnect(); /* disconnect from whichever wifi you're connected to */
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = mainWifiObj.getConnectionInfo();
        String str = wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "");
        System.out.print("wifiInfo.getSSID()1: " +str);
        if(str.equals(ssid)){
            //            mainWifiObj.disconnect(); 
            //            mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(false);
            isSameWifi = true;
            System.out.print("\nSSID is same1");
        }else{
            isSameWifi = false;
            System.out.print("\nSSID is different1");
        }
        mainWifiObj.enableNetwork(selectedConfig.networkId, true);
        mainWifiObj.reconnect();
        System.out.println("Connection exists in past, enabling and connecting priority =  " + highestPriorityNumber);
    }

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    {
        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
        builder.setSsid(ssid);
        builder.setWpa2Passphrase(key);

        WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

        NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder1 = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        networkRequestBuilder1.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        networkRequestBuilder1.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);
        
        NetworkRequest nr = networkRequestBuilder1.build();
        System.out.println("Android sdk version is 29 above NetworkRequest");
        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
        cntx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        System.out.println("Android sdk version is 29 above ConnectivityManager");
        ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback = new
                ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network)
                    {
                        super.onAvailable(network);
                        System.out.println("onAvailabile" + network);
                        cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLosing(@NonNull Network network, int maxMsToLive)
                    {
                        super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive);
                        System.out.println("onLosing" + network);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLost(@NonNull Network network)
                    {
                        super.onLost(network);
                        System.out.println("onLost" + network);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onUnavailable()
                    {
                        super.onUnavailable();
                        System.out.println("onUnavaliable");
                    }
                };
        System.out.println("Android sdk version is 29 above NetworkCallback");
        cm.requestNetwork(nr, networkCallback);
    }
    else
    {

        /* Make new connection */
        WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
        config.SSID = quoted(ssid);
        config.priority = highestPriorityNumber + 1;
        config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        if (securityType == WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK) {
            config.preSharedKey = quoted(key);
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
            config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
            config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        }else {
            config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        }

        System.out.println("Attempting new wifi connection, setting priority number to, connecting " + config.priority);

        int netId = mainWifiObj.addNetwork(config);
        //    mainWifiObj.disconnect(); /* disconnect from whichever wifi you're connected to */

        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) cntx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) { /* Check for all networks are forget in mobile. */
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = mainWifiObj.getConnectionInfo();
            String str = wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "");
            System.out.print("wifiInfo.getSSID(): " +str);
            if(str.equals(ssid)){
                //            mainWifiObj.disconnect();
                //            mainWifiObj.setWifiEnabled(false);
                isSameWifi = true;
                System.out.print("\nSSID is same");
            }else{
                isSameWifi = false;
                System.out.print("\nSSID is different");
            }
        }
        mainWifiObj.enableNetwork(netId, true);
        boolean isConnect = mainWifiObj.reconnect(); // todo?
        System.out.println("Is Connect -> " + isConnect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hii @Hemantz. Did you find the solution  for that issue. Because I am also facing same issue. If you find that can you please tell me?  Thank you.

Comment: I have not found solution on this code, but I have one way out for this.

Comment: What is that solution?

Comment: Actually, I have launching Settings -> Wi-Fi list page through android intent,                          // launch Wi-Fi settings page
cntx.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));                                   and connect the Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hi HemantZ. Did you send the SSID or did you directly navigating the user to wifi settings page. if he is there then which wifi he will choose from that?

Comment: @vijju I am directly navigating the user to Wi-Fi setting page. but before that I have stored SSID and password of Wi-Fi in application.

Comment: Did you try adding
`.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_RESTRICTED)
    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)`
into the `networkRequest`?

Comment: The WifiNetworkSpecifier works for peer to peer connections. It stablishes a connection to do some work but the rest of the device is not able to use the internet in through this connection. After the work binded to the process is done, the connection is ended. As far as I can tell, there's no way to force by command the device to connect to a specific network from the Android 10 and above.